# Eclipse UML plugin with Java Code Generation

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, code-generation, uml

Does anyone know of a good (read: Free) Eclipse UML plugin that can also do code generation? If not, does anyone know of any good Eclipse UML plugins?

**EDIT**: I'm running Eclipse IDE on Fedora Linux

TIA

Noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eUML is free (read the license for restrictions): http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/features/

Also Jupe: http://jupe.binaervarianz.de/

Comment: YES! These are perfect! Both are eclipse plugins and both do code generation/synchronization... thanks very much!

Comment: Be careful because you get UML annotation in your code @UML ..... All your code format will be changed be the tool. A real misery and very dirty code. I had a nice wel written code and after reversing my java code all my format was changed and plenty of uml annotations written. My code was a real mess and the worth is when I tried to refactor my code I lost all my diagrams because it seems that UML annotations was also erased.

Comment: FROM eUML FAQ: 1. I wondering if I can use free version of eUML2 software for commercial use?

Sure. You can use eUML2 free edition for your commercial developments. For more detail information, please read the license file.

Comment: @UMLGURU - I know this is an old comment, but you should always use a local version management system at least. I rely on git/hg for all my projects, and it's magic. Finally nothing can destroy my work. Just perfect, comfy.

Answer (score 2):

I've had some luck creating UML diagrams based on java code with ObjectAid: [ObjectAid Download Page](http://www.objectaid.com/download).

It was made for Eclipse so it should work. However, I don't know if it does code generation... but it makes a pretty picture!

The site lays out how to install it and the UML diagramming portion is absolutely free!

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Acceleo](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/) . Very flexible.

Comment: thanks! I don't see any UML based features, however. Thanks again.

Comment: Here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Demonstrations they mention a UML to Java demo

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans came with a free version of UML plugin which did code generation. The last version with UML plugin was 6.7. After that they stopped. you can download that and then install the plugin for it. You can check out [STARUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention, I'm running eclipse on Linux, though I STARUml looks good. Thanks again!

Comment: Netbeans can work on Linux too. I don't think that should be a issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jordi Cabot. you can basically exploit the Eclipse Modeling Framework with one of the existing model editors (i.e. Papyrus, TopCased, etc.). Then you can write your own generation workflow by means of Acceleo, an Eclipse implementation of the MOF to Text Transformation Language. It enables you to dive into a model and generate the text you want (i.e. Java, C++, C, python, Matlab, etc.) from it.

At the beginning it may look a bit weird and hard to understand but it is the best environment I know for this purpose. It is totally conform to the OMG standards.

Bye