# Eclipse UML Tool

Tags: eclipse, plugins, uml

I already tried a few tool for eclipse which are for building UMLs (Object/Dependency Diagrams), but what I really need is a tool to generate such an **UML out of code**. (and not vice versa)

I'd prefer a simple UML tools which is easy to install and don't has any dependencies. I already tried Jupe, Omondo and eUML, but anyhow I'm still not really happy with them.

(I also found this: [Eclipse UML plugin with Java Code Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672082/eclipse-uml-plugin-with-java-code-generation))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the most common CASE tools like [MagicDraw](http://www.nomagic.com/) or [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/).
They have reverse engineering capabilities and they are most powerful (especially auto formatting the diagram elements may be useful).

If you want / need to stay inside Eclipse, have a look at [this topic which is very similar to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790508/uml-tool-for-reverse-engineering-an-eclipse-project).